# browser display code not page

Tags: html, node.js, amazon-web-services

I am a rookie. Recently, there is a weird thing happens to my site built on AWS. If I access it from my desktop, everything looks fine. However, when I switched to my mobile browser or other persons'= computers, it just displayed the source-code. Please save my ass from this annoying situation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't really shown us anything to go on. No one will be able to help you as is. Source code is always a start.

Comment: Thanks for remind me. Please check the http://107.20.200.98:9000/

Comment: That works fine for me. What browser are you using and what browser are other people you've tried using? I'm on Chrome.

Comment: So that is the weird thing. Friends around me keep loading the source-code instead of page. They use the chrome on Mac like me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the `Content-type` as a actual [response header](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_setheader_name_value):

```
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

The `<meta http-equiv>` will only be parsed if the browser at least tries to read the file as `text/html`. If it opts to skip such a trial, as at least a few seem to do, then it'll just print out the file as `text/plain`.